# How do I calculate 6/12/36-month momentum of individual stocks?

Tags: momentum, calculation

I am looking at a particular dataset that contains 1/6/12/36 month momentum variables for individual stocks that were calculated based on Jagadeesh & Titman (1993), but I cannot figure out how the authors of the dataset calculated the 6/12/36 month momentum of individual stocks.

Let's say I have the following monthly data for an individual stock:

[image]

According to the authors of the dataset the corresponding 1/6/12/36 month momentum values at **October 2016** are:

[image]

For October 2016, I get that the 1 month momentum at $t=0$ is simply $\frac{Price_{t-1} - Price_{t-2}}{Price_{t-2}}$, which is $\frac{7.67-7.36}{7.36} = 0.0421195...$, but I am missing how I should calculate longer periods. Is there anyone who could tell me how I can calculate the 6-month momentum value (-0.0378...) in the example above?

**UPDATE:**
I found the answers. There was no way you could have answered this question with the figures above. First of all, the 6-month momentum is calculated as the 5-month cumulative return ending one month before the month's end. Same for the 12-month momentum, except that it is the 11-month cumulative return. The 36-month momentum is the cumulative return from months t-36 to t-13. Moreover, the authors use dividend adjusted returns which wasn't completely obvious.

Comment: I am also struggling with the momentum. Which is the paper mentioned in your questions? Could you tell me the name and the authors? I think it'll be very useful for me. Thank you

Comment: Momentum usually excludes the last period as that has quite a lot of reversal tendency. https://som.yale.edu/sites/default/files/Momentum,%20Acceleration,%20and%20Reversal_0.pdf has a discussion on this

Comment: @Ivy To calculate 6/12/36 month momentum according to Jegadeesh & Titman do the following. Download the monthly returns for your stocks, denote them by:
$$
r_{i,t}
$$
Subsequently apply the following formula to calculate the 6 month momentum:
$$
((1 + r_{i, t-2}) * (1 + r_{i, t-3}) * ... * (1 + r_{i, t-6}) - 1)
$$
For the 12-month momentum:
$$
((1 + r_{i, t-2}) * (1 + r_{i, t-3}) * ... * (1 + r_{i, t-12}) - 1)
$$
Do the same for the 36-month momentum, but start from month t-13 onwards:
$$
((1 + r_{i, t-13}) * (1 + r_{i, t-14}) * ... * (1 + r_{i, t-36}) - 1)
$$

Hope I helped!